# Error bars wont plot on y-axis in R

Tags: r, plot, errorbar

I have a log scale on my y axis, and the values are negative. I am using the 'segments' function to plot my error bars. The error bars are coming up on my x axis but not y.

Here is my script:

```
massaxis<-read.table("mass_axis.dat", header=TRUE)

x<-log((massaxis$mass))
y<-log((massaxis$semimajoraxis))
plot(x, y, type="p",
     main="Log(semi-major axis) vs Log(mass) for all known exoplanets",
     ylab="log(Semi Major Axis) (AU)",
     xlab="log(mass) (mass in jupiter mass (Mj))")

fit<-lsfit(x, y, intercept=TRUE)
print(summary(fit))

a<-log(0.431)
b<-log(0.0556)
sigma<-0.095
delta<-0.0126
alo<-a-sigma
ahi<-a+sigma
blo<-b-delta
bhi<-b+delta

segments(alo, b, ahi, b, col="red")
segments(bhi, a, blo, a, col="red")
points(a, b, col="red")
```

I have a graph with lots of points plotted, and then I am over plotting the errors for one particular point. A friend suggested that I set limits on my axis, but this did not solve my problem.

Please help!!

Comment: we don't have access to your dataset (or just subset). You can use dput() and include it in your post. Just run dput(dataset) in R.

Comment: do you *really* want `segments(alo, b, ahi, b, col="red")` or should that be `segments(alo, a, ahi, a, col="red")` (and correspondingly for the other `segments()` statement?)